# How to do robust thread-local storage in iOS

Tags: ios, c, cocoa-touch, pthreads, thread-local-storage

I'm having some problems with apparently getting wrong results from `pthread_getspecific` in a library that's designed to link into various iOS apps.

I see that [Apple writes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html):

> Cocoa and POSIX store the thread dictionary in different ways, so you cannot mix and match calls to the two technologies. As long as you stick with one technology inside your thread code, however, the end results should be similar. In Cocoa, you use the threadDictionary method of an NSThread object to retrieve an NSMutableDictionary object, to which you can add any keys required by your thread. In POSIX, you use the pthread_setspecific and pthread_getspecific functions to set and get the keys and values of your thread.

Does that mean that *neither* the Cocoa nor POSIX TLS functions can be expected to work in library code when we don't know whether the code that calls us is already using one or the other?

How does one get to store and retrieve a thread-local pointer robustly in these circumstances?

Is there a native Darwin TLS support API we should be using instead of either Cocoa or POSIX?

Comment: **Resolved**: The symptoms that initially made me suspect malfunction of pthread_getspecific turned out to be caused by dangling pointers left by an unrelated race condition elsewhere in the program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the point that Apple's docs are making is that you cannot use `pthread_setspecific` to set a value and then expect it to be available in `threadDictionary`. I wouldn't expect them to directly interfere with each other; they're just separate.

That said, if this is iOS-specific code, then [the strongly preferred way](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html) to manage this is with GCD rather than POSIX threads. GCD offers the equivalent of TLS in the form of `dispatch_get_specific`, `dispatch_queue_get_specific` and `dispatch_queue_set_specific`. But it also provides much better thread management than POSIX threads.

Comment: Interference would be such a nice explanation for the crashes we're seeing, though ...
It's an iOS-specific glue layer for existing code that wants to see a common abstraction for all the multitude of platforms it runs on. Getting into a vendor lock-in that wants to usurp the role or our existing well-working concurrency concepts is not an option.

Comment: (There was no interference after all, just a concurrency snafu elsewhere in the program that caused some pointers to dangle).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using C++, boost has [`thread_specific_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html). It supports iOS. If you don't want to use C++, the implementation probably offers some hints on how to make it work without a lot of external dependencies.